# Attribute and Functions in constructor

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, attributes, lambda

I want to do this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, 
                Inherited = false, 
                AllowMultiple = true)]
sealed class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    readonly string showName;
    readonly Type controlType;

    public Type ControlType
    {
        get { return controlType; }
    } 

    readonly Func<Control, object> selector;

    public Func<Control, object> Selector
    {
        get { return selector; }
    } 


    public MyAttribute(string showName, 
                       Type controlType, 
                       Func<Control, object> selector)
    {
        this.showName = showName;
        this.controlType = controlType;
        this.selector = selector;
    }

    public string ShowName
    {
        get { return showName; }
    }

}
class Foo
{
    // problem. Do you have an idea?
    [My("id number", 
     typeof(NumericUpDown), 
     Convert.ToInt32(control=>((NumericUpDown)control).Value))] 
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I want to do attribute that contains name, type of control, and selector for take from the control the value of the property.

I try do it, and can't.

Comment: You are re-inventing PropertyGrid.  Not taking advantage of all of its plumbing (TypeConverter, UITypeEditor) would be a mistake.  Best thing to do is to think ahead and ask yourself how you are going to create a functional editor for these properties.  Details like control location and size matter a great deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use an anonymous method or lambda expression in an attribute decoration.

Incidentally, if you could, it would be (moving the `control` declaration):

```
control=>Convert.ToInt32(((NumericUpDown)control).Value)
```

But... You can't. Either use the string name of a method that you resolve with reflection, or use something like a subclass of the attribute class with a virtual method override instead.

Comment: @zardav with someType.GetMethod(string)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use lambda expressions in attribute declarations. I had this problem too and sloved it by using a dictionary with a string as key for the lambdas. In the attribute I then only declared the key given to the lambda.

```
Dictionary<string, Func<Control, object>> funcDict = new Dictionary<string, Func<Control, object>>();
funcDict.Add("return text", c => c.Text);
```

The attribute is used like this:

```
[MyAttribute("show", typeof(TextBox), "return text")]
```